# Executing Python application built with Pyinstaller gives "Failed to execute script main"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a python program that uses `tkinter` for the GUI. My python project is a PyCharm project. It is organized as 
 
 `Project\main.py` 
 `Project\my_class.py` 
 `Project\images\favicon.ico` 
 `Project\common\util\util1.py` 
 `Project\common\util\util2.py` 
 `Project\venv` 
 
 Inside the terminal I move to `C:\..\Desktop\Project` folder and run `pyinstaller --windowed main.py` 
 If someone wonders what is the output in the terminal here it is

```
62 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
62 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
62 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
62 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main.spec
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
62 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Project',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Project']
62 INFO: checking Analysis
78 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
78 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
78 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
78 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2124 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2124 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
3900 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3900 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main.py
4306 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
5040 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
5040 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
5925 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
7668 INFO: Loading module hooks...
7668 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
7671 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7743 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
7747 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
7845 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
7846 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
8092 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
8150 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
8327 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8328 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
8742 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
8742 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
8742 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
8742 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
9133 INFO: checking Tree
9133 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
9148 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
9211 INFO: checking Tree
9211 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
9211 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
9258 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
9273 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
9273 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
9289 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
9289 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
9289 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
18180 INFO: Looking for eggs
18180 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
18180 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
18180 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\build\main\warn-main.txt
18445 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\build\main\xref-main.html
18492 INFO: checking PYZ
18492 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
18492 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
19259 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
19274 INFO: checking PKG
19274 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
19274 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
19290 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
19290 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
19290 INFO: checking EXE
19290 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
19290 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
19290 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\build\main\main.exe
19306 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
19306 INFO: checking COLLECT
19306 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
19306 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
22581 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

And here the error 
[image: error_image]

How can I solve this problem? Have you any idea?

Comment: Run pyinstaller without the `--windowed` parameter. Then run the resulting main.exe from console. The console should show additional error traceback which will help you identify the root problem.

Comment: @Xukrao here the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`

Comment: It happens regularly that pyinstaller is unable to automatically detect a few of the packages used by your script. In this case you have to give pyinstaller a hand by specifiying these 'hidden' packages manually. See [Listing Hidden Imports](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports).

Comment: @Xukrao I tried and I don't know if I did it right, but now on the terminal, it prints a `Traceback ...` with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'`. That's what you mean as "listing hidden imports"?

Comment: When you encounter a `ModuleNotFoundError`, add a pyinstaller [`--hidden-import MODULENAME`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) parameter for that module. Keep doing this until you don't get errors anymore.

Comment: @Xukrao I tried, but it says `Hidden import 'win32com' not found` and if I try to install it via `pip install win32com` I get this error `No matching distribution found for win32com`. How to link this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

- install `pywin32` to fix the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'` in the `venv\Lib\site-packages` folder of the `Project`
- install `tornado` in the `venv\Lib\site-packages` folder of the `Project`
- open terminal and move to the project folder
- run `setlocal`
- run `set PATH=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;%PATH%`
- run `pyinstaller -y -D --paths "C:\Windows\System32\downlevel" --paths "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\Lib\site-packages" main.py`
- copied the `images` folder from `Project` into the `dist` folder made by `pyinstaller` to get the `favicon.ico` in my GUI

Now I can run it either from the terminal or by double-clicking

Answer (score 1):

Try to set PATH and include all necessary paths

```
setlocal
set PATH=C:\Python37;%PATH%

pyinstaller -y -D --name Your_program_name--paths "C:\Windows\System32\downlevel" --windowed -i C:\ICONS\AI-2.ico --clean --distpath="." -p "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\whatever_is_needed" main.py
```

I also always rename the main.py to main.pyw
If you still get errors, or nothing, try to run the *.exe from cmd an see if any errors where shown.

Comment: with `set PATH=C:\Python37` you mean that I have to add my `Python37` folder or exactly what you wrote? Because I don't have that folder in `C:`

Comment: also in `-p` I have to add all the packages that I need which are in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\Lib\site-packages` or in my `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages`

Comment: 1) your python path

Comment: 2) I´m not shure, but you can add multiple paths, separated by ‘:’, or use this option multiple times